# How to make drawables and other design items for different resolutions?

Tags: android

I'm a new on Android, have checked official guide for my questions but I haven't found it. I need to make drawables for different layout, but I don't know what means mdpi, ldpi, hdpi - which range of resolution values should I use for each drawables? For example, from 100x100 to 200x200 px for mdpi, ...x... for ldpi, etc

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this page http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html